# Randomly generating @param names for inserting into sql query

Tags: c#, sql

hi i am writing a c# console application to migrate data from one database to another.
There are images in rows of the database and i need to include these images using @param into SQL statements, and using ADO.NET i am executing these statements.

I need to generate random strings that can be used as names for the @param and i am doing something like this.

```
    While(blah blah)
    {
    if (bVisitorPhoto != null)
            {
                string Picture = RandomString();
                SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
                picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
                picparameter.ParameterName = Picture;
                picparameter.Value = bVisitorPhoto;
                command.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
                VisitorPhoto = "@"+Picture;
             }
         string query = "insert into table Values (Picture, "PersonName");       
    }

 public static string RandomString()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        string Random_String = "str" + rand.Next(9999999).ToString();
        return Random_String;
    }
```

The problem is this error

> "SqlClient.SqlException" The variable name '@str5440049' has already
>   been declared.

how is this happening??? But once i ran the program in debug mode by pressing F11 like a million times i dint face this error

Comment: Your `RandomString` needs to be more sophisticated than that: [random numbers can repeat](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator), so you should make sure you're dropping the ones that you've seen in the same query to avoid once-in-a-blue-moon bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use random and not just the column name + counter value?

```
int counter=0;
While(blah blah)
{
  if (bVisitorPhoto != null)
  {
    string Picture = photo+counter.ToString();
    SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
    picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
    picparameter.ParameterName = Picture;
    picparameter.Value = bVisitorPhoto;
    command.Parameters.Add(picparameter);
    VisitorPhoto = "@"+Picture;
  }
  string query = "insert into table Values (Picture, "PersonName");       
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: +1 For fixing the underlying problem (not to mention, I wouldn't know how a stored procedure could deal with randomly named parameters.)

Answer (score 3):

You should not create a new `Random` object for every method call.  Instead, create it once, and store it in a member variable:

```
private static readonly Random _rand = new Random();

public static string RandomString()
{
    return "str" + _rand.Next(9999999).ToString();
}
```

As a more detailed explanation, the `Random.Random()` constructor uses a [time-dependent default seed value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329887%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  If there is not enough time between multiple constructor calls, the seed value will be identical.  And if you start with an identical seed, the sequence of generated numbers is always the same.